# Powershell 5.1, (ab)using DynamicParam to define function and script-level variable

Tags: powershell

In my scripts I use my company's logging system. To ease the usage, I added a few functions and parameter to my scripts. Basically, the scripts look like

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet('Off','LogAlways','Critical','Error','Warning','Informational','Verbose','Debug')]
            [string]$LogLevel # to override the value in config file
    )

begin   {
    
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    $errorActionPreference = 'STOP'
    
    $script:LogLevels = @{

        Off             = @{ level = -1; errcode = ''      }
        LogAlways       = @{ level =  0; errcode = '-'     }
        Critical        = @{ level =  1; errcode = 'CRIT'  }
        Error           = @{ level =  2; errcode = 'ERROR' }
        Warning         = @{ level =  3; errcode = 'WARN'  }
        Informational   = @{ level =  4; errcode = 'INFO'  }
        Verbose         = @{ level =  5; errcode = 'VERB'  }
        Debug           = @{ level =  6; errcode = 'DEBUG' }
    }

    function Set-DefaultLogLevel {
        [CmdletBinding()]
            param (
                [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet('Off','LogAlways','Critical','Error','Warning','Informational','Verbose','Debug')]
                    [string]$Level='Critical'
            )
            
        process {
        
            [...]
        }
    }

    function Write-Log {
        [CmdletBinding()]
            param (
                [parameter(mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet('Off','LogAlways','Critical','Error','Warning','Informational','Verbose','Debug')]
                    [string]$Level='Informational',
                [parameter(mandatory=$true , position=0)]
                    [string]$Text
            )

        process {
        
            [...]
        }
    }

}

Process {

    [...]
}
```

the problem is that the `ValidateSet` is repeated again and again on multiple functions and its values are also used to define data structures as `LogLevels` and others. so, to have only one source of the truth for the data structure/ `ValidateSet`, I modified the scripts to use dynamic parameters.

I wrote an ancillary `New-DynamicParameter` and based all definitions on the `LogLevels` data structure.

But... to be able to use them in the script-level `DynamicParam` block, I need to define them INTO that very block.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
    param ( )

DynamicParam {

    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    $errorActionPreference = 'STOP'

    function New-DynamicParameter {
        param(
            [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
                [string]$Name,
            [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
                [string[]]$ValidateSet
        )
            
        [...]
    }

    $script:LogLevels = @{

        Off             = @{ level = -1; errcode = ''      }
        LogAlways       = @{ level =  0; errcode = '-'     }
        Critical        = @{ level =  1; errcode = 'CRIT'  }
        Error           = @{ level =  2; errcode = 'ERROR' }
        Warning         = @{ level =  3; errcode = 'WARN'  }
        Informational   = @{ level =  4; errcode = 'INFO'  }
        Verbose         = @{ level =  5; errcode = 'VERB'  }
        Debug           = @{ level =  6; errcode = 'DEBUG' }
    }

    New-DynamicParameter -Name 'LogLevel' -ValidateSet $LogLevels.keys
}


begin   {
    
    Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
    $errorActionPreference = 'STOP'
    
    if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('LogLevel')) {
                
        $PSBoundParameters.Add('LogLevel',$null)
    }
            
    $LogLevel = $PSBoundParameters['LogLevel']

    
    function Set-LogLevel {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param( )

        DynamicParam {

            New-DynamicParameter -Name 'Level' -ValidateSet $LogLevels.keys
        }

        begin {
            
            if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Level')) {
                
                $PSBoundParameters.Add('Level','Critical')
            }
            
            $level = $PSBoundParameters['Level']
        }

        process {

            [...]
        }

    }

    function Write-Log {
        [CmdletBinding()]
            param (
                [parameter(mandatory=$true , position=0)]
                    [string]$Text
            )

        DynamicParam {

            New-DynamicParameter -Name 'Level' -ValidateSet $LogLevels.keys
        }

        begin {
            
            if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Level')) {
                
                $PSBoundParameters.Add('Level','Informational')
            }
            
            $level = $PSBoundParameters['Level']
        }

        process {

            [...]
        }
    }

}   

process {
        
        [...]
}
```

I ckecked but found nowhere the definition of what is allowed/ forbidden/ acceptable/ legit/safe in a `DynamicParam` block. Obviously, defining function and script-level variable works but is it safe or dis-recommended?